# Accessing Multiple Databases in Craft

Tags: craft3, database

Is there a way to access another database outside of the one Craft uses for its content? I need to able to access data fields from an external source for a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 8):

From your `config/app.php` file you could do something like this:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'otherDb' => [
            'class' => craft\db\Connection::class,
            'driverName' => 'mysql',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;port=3306;',
            'username' => 'myuser',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
            'enableSchemaCache' => !YII_DEBUG,
        ],
    ],
]
```

You might not need all of those depending on what you're doing.

Then from PHP, could access it like:

```
Craft::$app->otherDb->createCommand(...);
```

And from a template:

```
{{ craft.app.otherDb... }}
```

Comment: Well, that's fancy!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a free plugin to allow you to do exactly that: [Connect](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-connect)